# Bot isn't receiving updates from some chats

Tags: bots, telegram

My telegram bot with privacy set to off isn't receiving updates from t.me/ChatWarsMarket group but service messages. It works fine with every other group. Is there bug in telegram? How to recieve updates from this group?

Comment: Are you sure that your bot is in the chat? Which inscription is under the bot name in the members list: has it access to messages? When was your bot added, maybe at that time the group was private and private mode of the bot was enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is in chat. It has access to messages.

Comment: Try to remove and re-add the bot in the chat.

Answer (score 2):

Once the bot is added in a group, it remembers that privacy setting. If you change privacy settings via botfather actually it won't affect groups where the bot is already in. 
Probably this is what happened to you. The only way to get rid of this is to kick and re add the bot to use new privacy settings in that group